# How do I open a file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

How do I open a file in Python 3, like in a different program not as a text file.
All solutions I found online were like this

```
f1 = open("something.txt", "r")
print(f1.read())
f1.close()
```

but that just outputs the file contents. I want to open i.e. an .exe file as an executable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you take a look at [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a .exe file you can do it simply like this:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\Documents and Settings\flow_model\flow.exe")
```

You can also check [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

variant 1: start a program

```
import os
os.system("something.exe")
```

variant 2: start a program and read its output

```
import os
f1 = os.popen("something.exe")
print(f1.read())
```

variant 3: open text file in custom program (notepad.exe)

```
import os
s = os.system('notepad.exe something.txt')
```

variant 4: open text file by system, as double click in file explorer

```
import os
s = os.startfile('something.txt')
```